# Angular router optional params destroy/init component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using @angular/router

my routes:

```
{
        path: '',
        component: MyComponent,
    },
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: MyComponent
    }

}
```

is there any option to navigate between the two states('', ':id') without destory/init `MyComponent`

for example:

url: empty,
call `ngOnInit()`

url: `/some_id`,
call `ngOnDestory()`, `ngOnInit()` (destroy/build MyComponent)

Comment: yes. what you want to do `no parameter` and `id = 1` some value how it should behave. My suggestion is to use two different components instead.

Comment: I need the same component for the two options...

Comment: @YairTawil I understand what you wanted to say and I have the same problem. could you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ActivatedRoute` injector for this, as below,

```
export default class MyComponent {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
    .params
    .subscribe(params => {
        if(params['id']){
            /// perform some opeartion with id
        } else{
            // perform some other opeartion
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why? any valid reason??

Comment: on my app its expensive to call ngOnInit.
thanks anyway

Comment: if not `ngOnInit()` where you will handle the router changes??